# Rounding of calculated measure in MDX

Tags: rounding, mdx, ssas

How can i round a calculated mdx measure up to the nearest integer without having Excel on the server? The Excel-function is `CEILING(number, significance)`, but it is not possible to install Excel on the production ssas-server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is a Microsoft situation, you can use any VBA functions in your MDX to fiddle with strings or numbers. So `Round(xxxxxx, 2)` would work.

Comment: How do I use VBA functions in my MDX without Excel on the MSAS server?

Comment: You don't need Excel. If you are using Analysis Services, you just enter the VBA keywords into the MDX. No setup is required.

Comment: You may need to use VBA!round() to signify you are not using the built-in MDX Round() function which accepts only one argument.

Answer (score 1):

For the Floor function try Int function like:

```
Int([Measures].[Store Sales])
```

For the Ceiling function try Int + 1

```
IIF(([Measures].[Store Sales]) - Int([Measures].[Store Sales]) = 0, [Measures].[Store Sales], Int([Measures].[Store Sales]) + 1)
```